# console.log not working inside symfony application

Tags: javascript, symfony, console.log

I have this weird problem where console.log does not work inside symfony application. Logging works in other sites though, for example:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_output_console

Everytime i refresh that page, the console displays correctly: 11

here is the last part of my code inside the twig template

```
{% block javascripts %}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        console.log(5 + 6);
      });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The dropdown function works correctly, so javascript is working. However the console does not display anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to end your `<script>` tags that have an `src` attribute (like you did with jQuery). When writing JavaScript between tags, they need to be independant to that JavaScript specifically. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) for more information.

Specifically from the docs:

> If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags.

Here's your code updated with the fix:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        console.log(5 + 6);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you made my day! I feel like a major fool now.

Comment: No worries. It's always the simple things that trip us up! Myself included.